# show only first 10 li and show next then with a button or input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul id="asd">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
<li>12</li>
<li>13</li>
<li>14</li>
<li>15</li>
<li>16</li>

</ul>

<button id="prev" onSubmit="">prev</button>
<input id="page" onSubmit="" />
<button id="more" onSubmit="">next</button>

</div>

<script>
function showPage(page) {
    var listItems = $("#asd li").toArray();
    var start = (10 * page) - 10; // this is if you use page 1
    // var start = (10 * page) // this is if you use page 0
    var showListItems = listItems.splice(start, 10);

    $(listItems).hide();
    $(showListItems).show();
}
</script>
```

with help code got this far but cant get it work. so at this point i need my next and prev buttons switch between first 10 li item and last 10 10 by 10 and input field work as show Nth 10 . i ll have too many li tags in page entered by given values to another script. so if there is a way to force page to load only shown li items it will really helpfull.
Tried http://jsfiddle.net/uXn2p/1/ but its not really usefull for my situation.loads all content and not stoping after reaching last its just moving view area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create event (`pageChanged.pager`) on list to handle change of page number. Change page number appropriately, when buttons are clicked or input's value is changed, and trigger that event.

**UPDATED**: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/uXn2p/104/
**UPDATED 2**: Removed repetitive code by using custom event parameters

NB: I used custom event, in order to simplify the code and allow any part of your application to trigger changed page. Say after ajax request is finished. Also it is generally good practice to use namespaces, so if you need to destroy pager you can do something like `$('*').off('.pager')`

```
 var pageSize = 5
 , ul = $('#asd')
 , pages = Math.floor(ul.find('li').length / pageSize)
 , page = 0
 , currentPage = function (i) {
     return page*pageSize <= i && i < (page + 1) * pageSize 
 }

ul.on('pageChanged.pager', function( e , newPage ) {
  page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, newPage))
  $('#page').val(page)
  ul.find('li').hide().filter(currentPage).show();      
})

$('#prev').on('click.pager', function(e) {
    ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager', [--page])
})

$('#more').on('click.pager', function(e) {
   ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager', [++page])
})

$('#page').on('blur.pager', function(e) {
    ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager', [ +$(this).val() ])
})

ul.trigger('pageChanged.pager', [0])
```

Comment: % is the modulo operator, not the exact division. do pages=Math.ceil(ul.find('li').length/pageSize) to get the number of pages

Comment: I know (or guess) you just mistyped. they are too near in the keyboard xD.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli ikr! My brain runs much faster than my hands :D

Comment: haha it's the typical programmer syndrome. luckily for us, IDEs solve many (but not all) of these "tics". our beloved syndrome...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i ve tried it but cant get it work aswell. not hiding <li> s and buttons still not working. I m wrong at somewhere but cant find the point. a working example can be really good for me.

Comment: oh thhanks your editted code works great :) just when it hits last page it keeps goin for a empty page and when prev clicked starts showing content incorrectly as the last page only contain 1 li item. next goes like -11 12 13 14 15- -16- -blank- but prev goes like -blank- -16 15 14 13 12- where it must be just - 16-

Comment: yes i saw it :) only thing left in fiddle is the input field. shows page number perfectly but i wonder if its possible to make it go to desired page on submit. and input field effecting next and prev buttons function when you type a number and click next it goes a ramdom like page. sorry if im being to much.

Comment: Everything you are saying is already in last fiddle (100 or 101)

Comment: page = Math.max(0, Math.min(pages, +$(this).val()-1)) that -1 part solved the problem. at page 0 when you type 1 and hit next it goes to 2 not page 1 but with - 1 i gues it will be ok. thank you so much for your help and 1 last thing can we make that input valu on submit or onkeydown instead trigering with next or prev

Comment: @user3321234 pages were enumerated from 0 not from 1. Pretty easy to fix in other places.

Comment: thank you so much all done now. sorry dont know that much about java i just noticed that onsubmit and other thing was a pretty easy job and not good to ask :)